# Example Putting Registered Sign With NSString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Has anyone been successful in adding the registered sign symbol to their text using NSString in objective C? I tried using the unicode equivalent: \u00AE however this does not give me the registered sign symbol as should be! Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSLog(@"Hello\u00AE");` outputs the expected string with the registered character on my console. May be it's really the font you are trying to use when displaying your string.

Answer (score 2):

On a US keyboard, and probably others, you can just type it in with <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>: ®®®®®®®®®®®®

Alternatively, use the "Special Characters" panel from the Edit menu and drag and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the character as is (without unicode escaping it).  Same goes for copyright, and trademark characters.

Answer (score 0):

use NSLocalizedString for your in place string, something like NSLocalizedString(@"registered sign symbol",@""), and then in the InfoPlist.strings file add "registered sign symbol"="registeredsymbol";
InfoPlist.strings is utf8 or utf16 so you can enter the registered sign directly in there, there is some shareware apps like 'UnicodeChecker' that let you enter strange unichar characters.

Alternatively you can use +[NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chars length:(NSUInteger)length] to create a string from an array of unchar characters.